# Can I legally use a GNSS device in China?

Tags: china, gps-navigation

Can I legally use a GNSS device in China?

According to [Hvistendal (2013), Science](https://www.iris.edu/hq/BOD_2012/uploads/China_Arrowsmith_Science-2013-Hvistendahl-384-5.pdf):

> Since at least 
>   2007, it has been effectively illegal for foreigners to operate a GPS device in China.   International brands of cameras with GPS capabilities have been rigged to avoid displaying coordinates if the user is in China, says Stefan Geens, an analyst in Stockholm who  studies  networked  digital  maps  and  geospatial imagery.

On Quora, [different answers contradict each other](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-legal-for-a-foreigner-to-use-a-GPS-device-in-China), but at least one confirms the GPS-enabled camera rigging.

I usually carry a handheld Garmin GNSS device around, which includes the ability to receive GPS signals.  I have offline Openstreetmap data downloaded on the device.  If I do so in China, will I risk getting this device confiscated upon entry, or arrested for illegally using GPS?  I suspect that if GPS devices are illegal, then that also applies to GLONASS and Galileo (unless GPS is banned for being American...).  Does it?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/137256/2509

Comment: Also related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45231/2509

Comment: Very doubtful everyone is banned from using any GNSS. According to the BBC they will equip taxis with their own BDS system. https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-45471959 What they seem to actually ban is unathrorized map making https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_China#Legality Of course it can be iffy how one tells the two apart.

Comment: Just think that every smartphone has (A)GPS. I found [a page](http://en.miui.com/thread-81092-1-1.html) suggesting that it might be switched off for devices with a "China ROM", so presumably those for the Chinese domestic market. But I'm not sure that's the case for every manufacturer.

Comment: @Fizz Any GPS-receiver which has tracking switched on is collecting geographic data.

Comment: [Another discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/apfgh0/for_assisted_gps_agps_xiaomi_uses_state_owned/) however simply says just some default servers are different but otherwise the service probably works. Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45231/why-does-my-phones-gps-not-work-in-china

Comment: @Fizz Your link is about assisted GPS.  For regular GPS, I don't know what "default servers" you mean.

Comment: The problem is that laws and regulations in China are vague, and I suspect this is intentional, so that whatever the authorities decide is the law today it is. Look at the [baidu image issue](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/china-street-view-baidu-total-view) (probably related to camera gps issue).

Comment: @Fizz That sounds like an answer.

Comment: It seems that only the Chinese-made geolocation services (Baidu, Gaode, etc.) provide accurate locations in China. OpenStreetMap might do, but most likely the locations will all be shifted.

Comment: And of course, it's legal to use Baidu Maps and Gaode Maps. In fact, Apple's default map application switches to Gaode once you are in mainland China.

Answer (score 2):

This may well be one of those 'laws' or rules that is ultimately unenforceable.  There are so many mobile phones entering China daily in tourists' pockets, all of which are able to use GPS.  I imagine most tourists open up Google Maps (or at least try to), and the more prepared might use OpenStreetMaps (I have several friends who have used it there).

Ultimately it might come down to whether or not you interact with police, show your device, use it a lot, or blind luck, and whether they know the rule, enforce the rule, or even care.